# Scala 2.9 : Any way to use toArray on a Set inline

Tags: set, inline-code, scala-2.9, toarray

If the answer to my question is already out here please link it... I did look.

I'm working through some tutorials and it struck me a little odd that this code:

```
val my_set = Set("one","two","three")
println("First Value:" + my_set.toArray(0))
```

when run from the command line resulted in this error:

```
$ scala settoarray.scala 
/Users/rwheadon/devStuff/scala_sandbox/so_settoarray.scala:2: error: type mismatch;
found   : Int(0)
required: ClassManifest[?]
println("First Value:" + my_set.toArray(0))
                                        ^
one error found
```

I googled and searched SO for some direction on providing the ClassManifest[?] requirement but couldn't get anything to work inline.

Out of curiosity I tried to do the same simple toArray() into a val and pulled the array bound successfully:

Code:

```
val my_set = Set("one","two","three")
val my_arry = my_set.toArray
println("First Value:" + my_arry(0))
```

run from console:

```
$ scala so_settoarray.scala 
First Value:one
```

What I am wondering is if there's something I need to add when attempting to just do a quick inline conversion like my_set toArray(0) for a quick println of the first element? If I *must* set the result of a variable I can easily accept that but my guess is that I'm missing some small point here to make inline array casts work.

(... Scala **is** magic right?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `toArray` method takes an implicit argument of type `ClassManifest[A]`, where `A` is the element type. If you call it like `mySet.toArray(0)`, the compiler thinks you want to pass the implicit argument explicitly and then complains that it doesn't have the right type. To avoid that, you can write it like so:

```
mySet.toArray.apply(0)
```

Comment: I am very glad to see your answer. I've been seeing a lot about apply() but this specific case where it is "applied" became a lightbulb moment. Thanks a million.